# Pylint error VScode

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylint

I've recently changed my Python from 2.7.13 to 3.6.4 and when building my files through VScode, though everything works correctly, I keep getting a window showing:

There was an error in running the linter 'pylint'

and my console output show the following:

```
Linting with pylint failed.
Command failed: pylint --errors-only --msg-template='{line},{column},
{category},{msg_id}:{msg}' --reports=n --output-format=text c:\Users\OscarRamirez\Documents\Python\Tracker\Try.py
```

Comment: If that's all there is to the error, that's not too much. Can you run pylint by itself, on a command line? Just  as `pylint`.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong version of pylint. The current version you have in VS Code probably only supports Python2 code. There are many version of pylint, you may just have an old version that does not support python3.